# WordPress submenu of submenu dropdown issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having an issue with submenus within submenus showing when you click on the child li.

The issue i'm experiencing is when you click on the child li to open the sub-submenu, it's not adding the relevant class to the sub-submenu. Here's the jQuery i'm using.

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function() {

    var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');

    if(submenu.hasClass('menu-open')) {
        submenu.removeClass('menu-open');
      $(this).removeClass('menu-active');
    } else {
        $('.sub-menu').removeClass('menu-open');
        $('li').removeClass('menu-active');
        submenu.addClass('menu-open');
        $(this).addClass('menu-active');
    }

});
```

I'm thinking it's probably something to do with it trying to remove the 'menu-open' class from all 'sub-menu' classes when you click on a different li, but i'm confused on how to correct this.

Here's a link to my fiddle which will hopefully illustrate my problem in more detail than I can explain.

https://jsfiddle.net/08gckq8n/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue you are having is that you are trying to run the `on('click')` on the `li` and all your `.sub-menus` are INSIDE the top-level parent `li`. So no matter where you click, you're always clicking on the parent (the top most `li`), so you're not getting the results you expect.

Another issue you will run into is that you will not be able to open those links once your links are live, as you'll navigate to the page, rather than opening the `sub-menus`.

Here's code that simplifies your JS with a `toggleClass` and also appends an element to click on.

```js
var $menu_item = $('.menu-item-has-children');

$menu_item.append('<span class="caret"></span>');

$('.caret').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

li>.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.caret::before {
  content: '+';
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

li.menu-open>.caret::before {
  content: '-';
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-open>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="site-navigation">
  <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-8 menu-active">
        <a href="#">Root Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68">
            <a href="#">Subchild item</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-67">
            <a href="#">Subchild item</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-229" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-229">
            <a href="#">Subchild item with submenu</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-66">
                <a href="#">Sub-subchild item</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65">
                <a href="#">Sub-subchild item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/anbau0ya/5/

You will have to do a little styling for the `.caret`, but this will get you closer to what you want to do.

You can also adjust the output of the WP nav menu to include the `caret`, but that's an entirely different question/solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've managed apply the caret logic to my menu and everything is working as should now. I've accepted this as the answer to my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the code but you are on the right direction.

The selector of the click event is set to `.menu-item-has-children`, in the code there are two elements like this, the upper one in the hierarchy (lets call it "li wrapper") wrap all the menu links and that's a problem if you want to click each element at a time. take a look at the screenshot at right side of the window, the blue part is the li wrapper element area, every time you will click some link in the menu you will also click the li wrapper element, so you will get two elements in the event instead of one.
[image]

Now let's take a closer look at the code:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function() {

        var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');

        if(submenu.hasClass('menu-open')) {
            submenu.removeClass('menu-open');
          $(this).removeClass('menu-active');
        } else {
            $('.sub-menu').removeClass('menu-open');
            $('li').removeClass('menu-active');
            submenu.addClass('menu-open');
            $(this).addClass('menu-active');
        }

    });
```

On click of sub `.menu-item-has-children` element `submenu` variable will be set for two elements, the last one is the li wrapper.

The sub `.menu-item-has-children` element get the right class for it and for his child .sub-menu, but after the second element (li wrapper) comes in, it's removing the classes of the first `.menu-item-has-children` element and set the classes again to the li wrapper element.

So what to do from here?
first of all you can set the click event selector to `.menu-item-has-children a` to get on click only one element at a time and then call to his li parent in the `submenu` variable for finding the `.sub-menu` children. i prefer to show you shorter and simpler code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.menu-item-has-children a', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('> .sub-menu, .sub-menu.menu-open').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

On click, we search for the children of the element by finding `> .sub-menu, .sub-menu.menu-open`, the first is for the direct `.sub-menu` child and the second is for closing `.sub-menu` children that already open. we use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for switching between the two situations so we don't need to check for check for the class and add extra actions of adding and removing classes:
https://jsfiddle.net/08gckq8n/84/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Looking at this approach, this would probably be my preferred way of doing things, however I have applied the way that disinfor has mentioned in the answer below already and have found that to be just as useful. If I encounter any problems with the current way I'm now doing it, i'll be sure to take this approach. Again, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Eran, Would you mind adjusting the fiddle to show how this would work with multiple menu items with dropdowns that also have dropdowns? I'm unable to get the previously opened dropdown to close when you click on a new menu item.

Comment: The fiddle I've been sent in the end of the answer working well, I'm not sure I'm understand what do you mean, please post a fiddle you have issues with